# GitLab job is stalling

Tags: mysql, shell, gitlab-ci

Currently I have a job in GitLab pipeline whose primary purpose is to validate MySQL statements (Developer change) before proceeding to the next stage in the pipeline.

For this purpose I am using MySQL official docker image with some modifications (removed need for root password). The script which is being  validated will be executed on the MySQL shell. When doing this, if there is an error in the script, the job stalls without proceeding and eventually timing out.

This is my job:

```
Validate branch MySQL DB image:
  stage: validate_branch_db_image
  image: registry.gitlab.com/some-path/mysql-validator

  script:
    - echo "Validating MySQL image for branch ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}"

    - service mysql start
    - mysql < schema/create-database-schema.sql

    - echo "Validation of MySQL image for branch ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME} is successful"
    - service mysql stop

  only:
    refs:
     - merge_requests
```

Note: I had to start the MySQL service manually because the image is being used as the job's execution context.

When line `mysql < schema/create-database-schema.sql` fails due to a syntax error, the job stalls. What's the cause of this?

I am not sure if this is the best way to validate SQL scripts. Please also advise if there is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying official GitLab CI services approach to run MySQL server.
You won't need to start\stop\manage MySQL yourself.

See docs:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/services/mysql.html
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/mysql/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Example:

```
services:
- mysql

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: hello_world_test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql

connect:
  image: mysql
  script:
  - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
```